# SSIS: Unable to Migrate Empty Column from Excel Source to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, data-conversion

I have set up a Data Flow Task Task with a Excel Source to OLE DB Destination.
I am accessing the Excel Source through Named Range - Table or view Data Access Mode.

My Preview is working perfectly but when I am trying to Run the SSIS Package it throws an error -

> The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

The issue is with one of the columns which is **totally empty** is being identified as a DT_WSTR column while the destination is actually a DT_NUMERIC column. I have tried Data Conversion to explicitly convert it but it did not work.

I just want the whole column to be uploaded as it is (blank with NULL values). This looks like quite a trivial issue but I am not able to work around through this.

Is there any way to fix it? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you design your ETL pipeline:

[image: ETL Pipeline]

If we go inside DFT Task, I have a named range called 'Figures'.

[image: Source Excel Data]

What you need is to convert column data types to suitable ones:

If we go into data conversion step, It gives:

[image: Data Conversion]

Now time to execute our package:

[image: RRRRR]

Note: Below is our table definition of destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FinalTable](
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Figures] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [EmptyField] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)
```

End Result:

[image: End Result]